# How do I pass a double value to my C mock function with cmocka will_return()?

Tags: c, unit-testing, mocking, cmocka

I am using [cmocka](https://cmocka.org) to unit test a C project.

I want to mock a call to another modules made in my C function under test. This function in the other module deals with doubles, not ints.  The `will_return` documentation says it passes integer values, and I can see that if I call `will_return(__wrap_other_func, 42.99)` then the value passed into `__wrap_other_func` and pulled out through `double value = mock_type(double)` will be `42.0`, not the desired `42.99`.

```c
double __wrap_other_func(double param) {
  check_expected(param);
  double value = mock_type(double); // will_return() has converted this, effectively rounding
  fprintf(stderr, "%lf\n", value);
  return value;
}

static void test_this_func(void **state) {
  (void) state;
  expect_value(__wrap_other_func, param, 1.0);
  will_return(__wrap_other_func, 42.99);
  int result = this_func(12.34); // this_func() will call other_func()
  ...
  assert(result == 0); 
  /* the assert is failing because the double 42.99 is converted to an integer,
     then back to a double, rounding off all the decimal places. */
}

> 42.0
```

Has anyone figured out how to pass doubles into the mock function with `will_return` or some other cmocka method?  I'm stuck on this.

I was expecting to be able to pass non-integer values to my mock function using cmocka.

When I tried that using `will_return()`, I found all double values were rounded to integer equivalents.

I have pored over the cmocka documentation and searched for cmocka examples online.

**Update 2023-11-19**
**I have a solution.**

The `cmocka` main repo at [cryptomilk](https://git.cryptomilk.org/projects/cmocka.git) was updated by Andreas Schneider so that mocks work with real numbers (floats and doubles) as expected.
Thank you Andreas!

With the 2023-11-17 head of the main branch built and installed on my system, this code now works as expected.

```
double __wrap_other_func(double param) {
  // verify that the expected value was passed in to the mock
  check_expected(param);
  // assign the return value
  double value = mock_float; 
// will_return_float() can deal with real numbers (doubles and floats)
  fprintf(stderr, "%lf\n", value); // this will print the real number value now
  return value;
}

static void test_this_func(void **state) {
  (void) state;
  // make sure the argument passed to the mock is correct
  expect_value(__wrap_other_func, param, 1.0);
  // tell the mock what to return
  will_return_float(__wrap_other_func, 42.99);
  // call this_func normally. The mock for other_func will get called
  int result = this_func(12.34); // this_func() will call other_func()
  ...
  assert(result == 0); 
  // the assert is now passing because the double 42.99 remains a double
}

> 42.99
```

Thanks to everyone who offered comments and answers.

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to cmocka or any other c unit test library for that matter, but I think there's good reason for cmocka to not allow `double` to be passed to `will_return` because comparing doubles is not really a good idea because of precision. How about changing the function to return an integer instead that represents a fraction of something? This is how it is generally worked around in embedded systems where floating point operations are costly. You could still expose the `double` function with a simple conversion between the two.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Marco!  In this case, the wrapped function performs a calculation on doubles, so changing its type and signature for mocking does not seem right.  Precision on the doubles can be managed in the test code.

Comment: How Marco suggests, cast the value to int (keeping the same byte size) before calling `will_return()`, then inside your function you cast it back to its original type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended way is to use `will_return_float` and `mock_float`

There are also other "assigning" macros:

- `will_return_int` `mock_int`
- `will_return_float` `mock_float`
- `will_return_ptr` `mock_ptr`
- etc.

to use instead of the "casting" macros `will_return` and `mock_type`

Side note: `mock_float` doesn't take macro arguments, as of now it stores the value as a [`double`](https://gitlab.com/cmocka/cmocka/-/blob/master/include/cmocka.h#L2700)

Comment: Pignotto, I was not able to get this to work with versions 1.1.5 through 1.1.7, but when I got some time yesterday to work on this again, I eventually fetched the latest (2023-11-17) version from the cryptomilk git and I was able to get it to work with `will_return_float` and `mock_float`. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that cmocka does natively offer a will_return_float or will_return_double macro. I was facing the same issue as you did and think I found a workaround involving to "trick" the mock() macro by using it to pass a pointer to a float. (**Edit:** I just realized that this is exactly the comment by https://stackoverflow.com/users/13199234/mem)
Anyway, taking your example, it would be:

```
double __wrap_other_func(double param) {
  check_expected(param);
  double value = *(mock_type(double*)); // "value" takes the content of the double pointer! 
  fprintf(stderr, "%lf\n", value);
  return value;
}

static void test_this_func(void **state) {
  (void) state;
  double wantedResult = 42.99;  // define your wanted result
  expect_value(__wrap_other_func, param, 1.0);
  will_return(__wrap_other_func, &wantedResult);  // pass the pointer to the double value wantedResult instead of the value itself.
  int result = this_func(12.34); // this_func() will call other_func()
  ...

}
```

This line

```
double value = *(mock_type(double*));
```

in the definition of `__wrap_other_func(double param)`
resolves to

```
double value = *((double*) &wantedResult;
```

which is identical to `wantedResult`.

Note the importance to pass the *pointer* to the `wantedResult` instead of the value in the `will_return` function.

Comment: I tried your method and I could not get it to work. I'm sure it was a me problem.
I shifted gears and dug into the changes the `cmocka` maintainers at [cryptomilk](https://git.cryptomilk.org/projects/cmocka.git/) are doing and found there are now examples in the main branch that show real numbers being passed into mocks and back out again.
This is not part of the latest release 1.1.7, but I pulled down the head of the repo, built it, installed it and I was able to get my mock to work as expected. I will update my OP with my new findings. Thank you for your thoughtful advice.